# My github.io showing 404 error in landing page?

Tags: github-pages, github-for-windows

I want to create my resume site with my github account.I create a index.html repositories and launch automatic page generator . The problem is  it showing my page in this [enter link description here](http://towhid1.github.io/index.html/) link. But I want to show it in this [enter link description here](http://towhid1.github.io) link.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

To generate User and Organization Pages sites, you'll need to create a repository named username.github.io . The username or organization name must be your own or your GitHub Pages site will not build. The automatic page generator is accessible via the repository's Settings page. You can read more about User and Organization Pages

visit : [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator/)